# Is database performance optimization independent of the size of a database or a table?

Tags: performance

If by rewriting an operation or a piece of code the performance has increased by 30% in a program reading and writing to a table with 100,000 records, does that optimization remains same if the table grows and would have 10,000,000 records i.e. still 30%?

Given that the hardware has not been modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sampling of your dev table (100k) remains consistent with the actual prod table, then the statistics should reveal the same query plan and so the increase in performance should hold pretty consistent. However that depends on making sure hardware is the same AND the load on the system is the same. When you say a 30% increase are we talking query time? IO Reads? CPU time? When developing, I always tell my developers to look at the performance in terms of reads (SET STATISTICS IO ON). CPU and query time can be dependent on many factors. But reads will always remain the same across hardware and any other load on the system at that time (just be sure to look at logical reads, not physical).

Comment: By 30% increase in the performance I mean IO reading time. It should probably then remain the same for the production table.

Comment: More or less, that is correct. With a sampling as large as yours it should be about the same. But now if you have a sampling of like 1k or maybe even 10k then it may be small enough to change the query plan (ie, maybe do nested loops instead of hash/merges).

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite answer. It really depends on the data and the change you have performed.

For instance, if you created an index that helped in the 100,000 records table, in many cases it will help with the 10,000,000 records table.

However, if, let's say, you had a cursor and you've rewritten it to a set based solution, it will be good enough for the 100,000 records table, but not good in the 10,000,000 records table because there is no supporting index for the query.

The best thing to do is to monitor the system as it grows and see if queries keep running fast or degrade, and fix accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Query plan generation is complicated.  The number of possible plans grows exponentially with the complexity of the query. Each possible plan will be optimal within a small range of data counts and distributions.  Change any one of these, however, and another plan becomes optimal.  Say you add an index.  This can be used for some range of counts and distributions.  For a different range the optimiser may chose a plan which does not use the index, so the index may as well not exist.  (Indeed, it's causing harm through slower INSERTs.)  This is why it is always best to test code against realistic production data.

In practice, however, most development occurs against "big enough" data sets with the expectation that the plans seen will be close enough to those produced by full-scale production data that the differences will not matter.  This seems to hold in practice, by-and-large.  There can be nasty surprises on launch day when it doesn't, however.

Of course if your code change is in the procedural application rather than the invoked SQL then most likey this will scale linearly and 30% relative improvement will be seen however many rows are pushed through.

The [PICASSO](http://dsl.serc.iisc.ernet.in/projects/PICASSO/) tool has helped me visualise the stability of plans with respect to changing statistics.